# fatal exception with getWritableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database manager class Below that is causing a fatal exception.  I am at a loss as to why and was hoping someone could tell me what im doing wrong or how i can fix it..

THE CODE:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "DataBaseManager";
    private static final int dbVersion = 1;// ++ for DB  changes

    static final String dbName ="LCInstore";
    //Table Names
    static final String allIcons = "Icons";
    static final String allScreens = "Screens";
    static final String isLookUp = "LookUp";

    //Column Names - LookUp
    static final String colIconID = "IconID";
    static final String colScreenID = "ScreenID";
    static final String colRank = "Rank"; // order

    //Column Names shared by tables: Screens and Icons
    static final String colID = "ID";
    static final String colType = "Type";
    static final String colName = "Name";

    //Column Names - Icons
    static final String colImage = "Image";
    static final String colLabel = "Label";
    static final String colIntent = "Intent";
    static final String colIParams = "Params";


    public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion); 
        mContext = context;
        Log.v(TAG, "Initaited");

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on create called");

        // Create Icon Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ allIcons +"" +
                "("+colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colImage + " BLOB," +
                    colLabel + " TEXT," +
                    colIntent + " TEXT," +
                    colType + " TEXT)");

        // Create Screens Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + allScreens +"" +
                 "("+colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colType + " TEXT)");

        //Create LookUp Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + isLookUp +"" +
                 "("+colIconID + " INTEGER, "+
                    colScreenID + " INTEGER," +
                    colRank + " INTEGER)");

         InsertInitData(db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on upgrade called");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+allIcons);




    }
    /*private void InsertInitScreens(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colName, "DR_Home");
           cv.put(colType, "dr_home");
           db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "DR_Sub");
           cv.put(colType, "dr_sub");
           db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv);
    }*/


    private void InsertInitData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //all Icons

        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon1", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon2", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon3", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon4", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon5", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon6", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromRes(this, "Icon7", R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon, "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon8", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon9", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon10", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon11", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");
        addIconFromWeb(this, "Icon12", "http://sapientboston.com/internal/elidd/red.png", "MY RED ICON", "someIntent", "generic");


        ContentValues cv2=new ContentValues();
        cv2.put(colName, "DR_Home");
        cv2.put(colType, "dr_home");
        db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv2);

        cv2.put(colName, "DR_Sub");
        cv2.put(colType, "dr_sub");
        db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv2);

        addIconToScreen(1, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(2, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(3, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(4, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(5, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(6, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(7, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(8, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(9, "DR_Sub");
        addIconToScreen(10,"DR_Sub");

    }
    public byte[] getBlobFromRes(int d) {
        byte[] blobData;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.mContext.getResources(),
                d);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        blobData = stream.toByteArray();
        return blobData;
    }

    public void addIconFromRes(DataBaseManager db,String name, int res, String label, String intent, String type ) {
        SQLiteDatabase mdb = db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colName, "Icon7");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(res));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY RED ICON 2");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           mdb.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);
    }



    public void addIconFromWeb (DataBaseManager db,String name, String url, String label, String intent, String type ) {
        new DownLoadImageTask (db, name, url, label, intent, type).execute(url);
    }

    private class DownLoadImageTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, byte[]> {
        String pName;
        String pLabel;
        String pIntent;
        String pType;
        SQLiteDatabase mdb;

        public DownLoadImageTask(DataBaseManager db, String name, String url, String label, String intent, String type ){
            pName = name;
            pLabel = label;
            pIntent = intent;
            pType = type;
            mdb = db.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(String... url) {
            byte[] blobData = null;
            DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(url[0]);  
            HttpResponse mHttpResponse;
            try {
                mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
                if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {  

                HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
                if ( entity != null) {  

                 //ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
                blobData = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);  
                 //mContext.getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);  
                } 
            } 
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return blobData;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {

            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
               cv.put(colName, pName);
               cv.put(colImage, result);
               cv.put(colLabel, pLabel);
               cv.put(colIntent, pIntent);
               cv.put(colType, pType);
               mdb.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);
         }

    }





    public void addIconToScreen(int id, String screenName){

       SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
       int hsID = getScreenID(screenName);
       int hsTotal = getScreenTotal(hsID)+1;

       Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ isLookUp +" where " + colIconID +  "="  +id + " and " + colScreenID +"=" +hsID, null);
       int numFound = c.getCount();

       if(numFound<1){
           ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colScreenID, hsID);
           cv.put(colIconID, id);
           cv.put(colRank, hsTotal);
           db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv);
       }

       // else do nothing

    }

    public int getScreenID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        int sID;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " +colName + "=" +name;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        sID = cursor.getInt(0);
        return sID;
    }


    public int getScreenTotal (int sID){

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        int rows = (int) db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + isLookUp + " where " + colScreenID + "="+sID).simpleQueryForLong();
        return rows;

    }

    public void DeleteScreenIcon (int screenID, int iconID){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(isLookUp, colScreenID + "=" + screenID + " and " +colIconID+ "="+iconID, null);
        db.close();
    }




    // GETTERS

    public ArrayList<Integer> getScreenIcons(String screenName) {

        int sID = getScreenID(screenName);

        ArrayList<Integer> iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + isLookUp + " where " + colScreenID + "=" +sID + " order by " + colRank;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                iconList.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "List Created"); 
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return contact list
        return iconList;



    }

    public String getIconLabel(int id){
        String label;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colLabel+ " FROM " + allIcons + " WHERE " +colIconID + "="+id; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            label = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        else{
            label ="";
        }
         cursor.close();
           db.close();
        return label;

    }

    public String getIconImage(int id){
        String image;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colImage+ " FROM " + allIcons + " WHERE " +colIconID + "="+id; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            image = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        else{
            image ="";
        }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();
         return image;

    }

    public int checkHomeScreen(Integer iD) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sID = getScreenID("DR_Home");
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        int rows = (int) db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + isLookUp + " where " + colScreenID + "="+ sID + " and "+ colIconID + "="+iD).simpleQueryForLong();
        return rows;
    }


}
```

And The ERROR:
[image: LOG ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     InsertInitData(db);
}
private void InsertInitData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    addIconFromWeb(this,..
}
public void addIconFromWeb (...
    new DownLoadImageTask (db..
}
public DownLoadImageTask(DataBaseManager db
    mdb = db.getWritableDatabase()
}
```

`SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` triggers `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` if your db does not exist. (and it does not because you are still in `onCreate()`)

Solution: use the supplied `SQLiteDatabase db` object to do all initialization (downloading from the web is imho a very bad idea here) The only thing you must not do is to use your `DataBaseManager db` inside that context since that will create the loop. You can safely use it once the database is created.

Downloading data and putting it into the database should be done from an outside context of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Through that class.

The purpose of `SQLiteOpenHelper` is to help you with opening a database that has the tables you need to work with. That's about it. You shouldn't do real heavy work inside that class since it would take ages now to open (`.getWritableDatabase()`) your database (or you have to expect that and work around that limitation if you choose so)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it would be to change your `DownLoadImageTask` constructor from this...

```
    public DownLoadImageTask(DataBaseManager db, <other parameters omitted>){
        ...
        mdb = db.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

...to this...

```
    public DownLoadImageTask(SQLiteDatabase db, <other parameters omitted>){
        ...
        mdb = db;
    }
```

Change your `addIconFromWeb(...)` method from this...

```
public void addIconFromWeb(DataBaseManager db, <other parameters omitted>) {
    new DownLoadImageTask (db, <other parameters omitted>).execute(url);
}
```

...to this...

```
public void addIconFromWeb(SQLiteDatabase db, <other parameters omitted>) {
    new DownLoadImageTask (db, <other parameters omitted>).execute(url);
}
```

Change your calls in `InsertInitData(...)` to...

```
private void InsertInitData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    addIconFromWeb(db, <other parameters omitted>);
    ...
}
```